# Probability of finding electron in a spherical shell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability

In the book *Arthur Beiser - Concepts of modern physics*, probability of finding an electron in Hydrogen atom in the spherical shell between $r$ and $r+dr$ is given as

\begin{equation}
P(r)dr = r^2|R(r)|^2dr\int_0^\pi|\Theta(\theta)|^2 sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}|\Phi(\phi)|^2d\phi =r^2|R(r)|^2dr
\end{equation}

because the normalization of angular part will give 1.

The probability from another argument is

\begin{equation}
P(r)dr = 4\pi r^2|R(r)|^2dr.
\end{equation}

The argument is that the **volume** of spherical shell between $r$ and $r+dr$ is $4\pi r^2 dr$ and Radial probability **density** is $|R(r)|^2$. Hence the probability of finding the electron in $r$ and $r+dr$ is **$4\pi r^2|R(r)|^2dr$**.

There is an apparent discrepancy of a factor of $4\pi$.  Could someone explain this? Which is the correct method?

Comment: If you integrate $R$ from zero to infinity it has to be 1. That might help finding the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular integral will give $4\pi$. To be precise, it is easy to check that $$\int_0^\pi d \theta \int_0^{2\pi} d \phi \sin(\theta) = 4\pi$$.

The normalization of angular part is 1, but that means (for s-type wave function) that
$$\int_0^\pi d \theta \int_0^{2\pi} d \phi |Y_{00}(\phi,\theta)|^2 \sin(\theta) = 1$$.

Here $Y_{00}(\phi,\theta)$ is the first spherical harmonic, $Y_{00}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}$.

It all comes down how you define $R(r)$, with or without spherical harmonic part. If we write

$$\Psi = R(r) Y_{00}(\phi,\theta)$$, then your second equation should read

$$P(r)dr = 4\pi |\Psi(r)|^2 r^2 dr,$$

which is consistent, since $|Y_{00}|^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$.
You basically forgot the angular part in your second derivation of the shell probability. If you put in the angular part there as $Y_{00}$ for example, it will give the same result.

It should be consistent, as mentioned in the comment, so that the probability density integrates to 1.

Comment: The definition of $R$ in second derivation is basically $R(r)*Y_{00}$. I got it now. Sometimes in textbooks they use it interchangeably. Thanks!